# RSI comes from oversold and overbought levels and cross levels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to code without success, would you please help to get only first signal for RSI when rsi comes from overbought level and cross 40 and rsi comes from oversold level and cross 60 level.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI test')
//inputs
rsiob60 = input(title='From overbought level (70) and crossover 60:', defval=60)
rsios40 = input(title='From Oversold level (30) and crossunder 40:', defval=40)

// Get indicator values
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
////============ calculations for new cross  



//
short  = ta.crossunder(rsi,rsiob60)
long = ta.crossover(rsi,rsios40)
//
plotshape(long, "Short", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(short, "Long", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
// Plot 
plot(rsiob60, title='Overbought short', color=color.new(color.red, 20))
plot(rsios40, title='Oversold long', color=color.new(color.green, 20))
plot(rsi, title='RSI', color=color.new(color.purple, 0))
hline(70, 'RSI Overbought Level', color.new(color.red, 50))
hline(50, 'RSI Middle Band', color=color.new(#787B86, 60))
hline(30, 'RSI Oversold Level', color.new(color.green, 50))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `var` to see if the rsi has gone below OS. Then check this flag at the time of the `crossover`.

Reset the flag when there is a `crossover`, so it will be ready for the next signal.

```
var is_os = false
is_os := ta.crossover(rsi, 40) ? false : (rsi < 30) ? true : is_os
```

**Note:** When there is a `crossover`, `is_os` above will be `false`. So, check its previous value with the history referencing operator like `is_os[1]`.

```
plotshape(Short and is_os[1], "Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
```

[image]